# How can I add the current DateTime to a SQL Server CE datetime column?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, sql-update, sql-server-ce, alter-table

We have code that updates a SQL CE table like so:

```
if (!IsValidColumn("platypi", "playtpus_id"))
{
    dynSQL = "ALTER TABLE platypi ADD playtpus_feed nvarchar(19)";
    dbconn.DBCommand(dynSQL,false);

    dynSQL = "UPDATE platypi SET playtpus_feed = 'Purina Platypus Chow'";
    dbconn.DBCommand(dynSQL,false);
}
```

IOW, if the column does not exist, create it, and then set each playtpus_name val to an empty string.

What about in the case of a timestamp column, though?

Suppose each platypus has a barcode on its poison toe that gets scanned before it is shipped out to Mammals R Us, and so we want to add a "time_scanned" column like so:

```
if (!IsValidColumn("platypi", "time_scanned"))
{
    dynSQL = "ALTER TABLE platypi ADD time_scanned datetime";
    dbconn.DBCommand(dynSQL,false);

    dynSQL = "UPDATE platypi SET time_scanned = '<What here?>'";
    dbconn.DBCommand(dynSQL,false);
}
```

Assuming we want to put the current time in the UPDATE...SET line, what should it be? How can I add that?

Based on [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275635(v=SQL.80).aspx), where it says, "Valid year range 1753-9999; valid second range 0-59" for "SQL Server CE specifics," should I do something like:

```
DateTime dt = Now;
dynSQL = String.Format("UPDATE platypi SET time_scanned = '{0}', dt.ToString()";
```

or...???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
UPDATE platypi SET time_scanned = GETDATE()
```

Assuming that time_scanned is a datetime column. Timestamp/rowversion is soenthing completely different, and not related to date and time

Comment: Thanks; yes, it is a datetime.